# Is there a way to speed-up the following code?

Tags: performance, r

Is there a way to speed-up the following R code?

```
actionVec<-NULL
for(iii in 1:length(resultTable$V1)){
actionVec[iii]<- sum(browse$V2==resultTable$V1[iii] & browse$V4 == i & browse$V5 == ii)}
```

this is a loop to form a vector for each record (row) in **resultTable**, containing the number of entries that match the conditions in table **browse**

this script runs 36 minutes. I suspect that there is a way to make it run much faster. I have experienced a reduction from 15 min to 10 ms (!) on another script when avoiding loops but using vectors. But in this case I can`t find out how to make it.

**EDIT1:**
variables **i** and **ii** come from outer loop and may be two arbitrary integers for this loop.

**EDIT2:** more complete version

```
SESSION_NUMBER<-length(resultTable$V1)

for(i in 1:55){ for(ii in 1:21){  
if(sum(browse$V4 == i & browse$V5 == ii) > treshold){
actionVec<-NULL
for(iii in 1:SESSION_NUMBER){
actionVec[iii]<- sum(browse$V2==resultTable$V1[iii] & browse$V4 == i & browse$V5 == ii)}
resultTable[,i+1] <- actionVec
}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is:

Since `i` and `ii` and `browse$V4` and `browse$V5` are outside of the loop, you can precalculate this before going into the loop. That way you can save a small bit of calculating.

`if (sum(browse$V4 == i & browse$V5 == ii) > treshold)`

I dunno what you're doing here, but from what I can see, you're calling `sum(1)` or `sum(0)`. Naturally, this produces `0` or `1`. Then you're comparing it to `treshold`. Well, if `treshold` is below 1 but not below 0, then you can just remove the check, as well as the for loop, since `browse` doesn't change in the for loop!

If `treshold` is below 0, then the check is not needed. Thus, (please check if my syntax is correct)

```
SESSION_NUMBER<-length(resultTable$V1)

if(treshold < 1 && treshold >= 0){
    //check if browse$V4 and browse$V5 are in range
    if(browse$V4 >= 1 && browse$V4 <= 55 && browse$V5 >= 1 && browse$V5 <= 21){
        actionVec<-NULL
        for(iii in 1:SESSION_NUMBER){
            actionVec[iii]<- sum(browse$V2==resultTable$V1[iii])
        }
        resultTable[,browse$V4+1] <- actionVec
    }
} else if (treshold < 0){
    for(i in 1:55){ 
        for(ii in 1:21){  
            actionVec<-NULL
            temp<-browse$V4 == i & browse$V5 == ii
            for(iii in 1:SESSION_NUMBER){
                actionVec[iii]<- sum(browse$V2==resultTable$V1[iii] & temp)
            }
            resultTable[,i+1] <- actionVec
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: thank you! will check the improved performance but I think there still might be a way to drastically improve performance

Comment: @YavpolnomShoke Any improved performance is likely going to be on a semantic level - the current code is too short to show me what else could be changed.

Comment: I added the wrapping loops (please see Edit2) but I think they cant be avoided so I focus on the inner one

Comment: @YavpolnomShoke I think they're really weird, please check my code and the idea, I don't know R (never used before) but your code seems weird to me, with the sums adding nothing but a single number